# nodejs, 'child.stdin.write' does not send the password to the child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

In my NodeJS app, I am spawning a process for an executable which prompts the user id and password.
I can send the input for the userid, but cannot for the password.
The below is the code snippet.

```
const nodeChildProcess = require('child_process');

let child = nodeChildProcess.spawn(binaryfile)
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    msg = String(data)
    if (msg.startsWith("userid")) {
        child.stdin.write("user\n"); // IT WORKS!
    } else if (msg.startsWith("password")) {
        child.stdin.write("password\n"); // IT DOES NOT WORK!!
    } 
});
```

I think it's somehow related with how the binary executable accepts the user password....
Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: I guess that `msg.startsWith("password")` is `false`

Comment: Hi @Konrad , it is True. I confirmed that the code flow goes through there.